# When does FTP server accept passive data connection from client?

Tags: c, ftp

I'm working on a simple ftp server in c. I don't know when ftp server accepts passive data connection from client. To my understanding here is how passive ftp works:

1. client sends "PASV" command to server
2. server creates and binds a socket, and listens on a random port.
3. server uses getsockname to get random port
4. assemble passive reply message in format: 227 Entering Passive Mode(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6).
   Note: server ip is a1.a2.a3.a4 and port number is: a5 * 256 + a6.

my question is: when does ftp server accepts the connection to said random port? should server accept data connection after sending reply? or should ftp server accept connection right before data connection is required, i.e. when client is requesting a file?

I have RFC959. is there any other useful ftp resource out there? google is not particularly helpful.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have the server start accepting connections on that port (by calling `listen()`) *before* sending the 227 reply. If you wait until after sending the 227, the client *may* try to connect before you're accepting connections, and get a "connection refused" error.

After calling `listen()` which starts the TCP system listening, you can call `accept()` whenever you're ready to start accepting connections. When to call that is an application-level decision (but obviously once the client sends a data transfer command, it will want to connect). Connections from the client will wait in an accept queue until the server actually calls `accept()`, which removes them from the accept queue.

Comment: is this what you meant:
1. client sends "pasv"
2. server sends reply with ip and port and start listening
3. client send "get filename"
4. server calls accept() and send the file

let me know whether I understand it correctly

Comment: That's correct. As long as you call `listen()` before sending the 227 reply back, you should be fine with that. You can test this by delaying for a few seconds after receiving the GET command, just to make sure that the client doesn't abort before you have a chance to `accept()`.

Answer (score 1):

It will open this port only when a transfer is required by the client. The server (which must know its own external IP address) will then tell the client where to connect, including IP (4 bytes) and port (in 2 separated bytes) so it can transfer the data. Something in this format:

```
printf("227 Entering Passive Mode (%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d)\n",
(unsigned int)((my_ip >> 24) & 0xff),
(unsigned int)((my_ip >> 16) & 0xff),
(unsigned int)((my_ip >> 8) & 0xff),
(unsigned int)(my_ip & 0xff),
(unsigned int)(this_session->pasv_port >> 8),
(unsigned int)(this_session->pasv_port & 0xff));
```

The port is used when user requires a LIST, RETR, STOR or some other transfering.

I guess the client in passive mode will require PASV always before any LIST, RETR or STOR, to do concurrent transfers.

I recommend you installing and studying FileZilla Client and Server. They both show up all the raw FTP talking so you can comprehend whats going on and what should happen for your program.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best resource on implementing FTP is http://cr.yp.to/ftp.html

There are also more recent FTP RFCs that you might find useful:

- http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt
- http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2228.txt
- http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3659.txt